# "to celebrate life" meaning

Tags: word-meaning

> They would like to "celebrate life" and their feative spirit is renowned.

I wish to know the meaning of "celebrate life" in this sentence.
I think it means "perform activities for pleasure".

Answer (score 1):

"Celebrate life" is literally celebrating that they are alive. Your "preform activities for pleasure" is correct, but with the caveat that they are doing so mostly because they still can. For instance, a gamer playing for hours on his laptop isn't usually "celebrating life." Note the including of the word "festive" in this sentence helps imply that meaning, as it could be said that celebrating life often has to do with religion or celebrations.

Answer (score 0):

To celebrate life means whatever you think life and celebrate mean.

So, if life means to you: living, working, breathing, or any other human activity relating to LIFE, and you enjoy that, you are celebrating (making a "party of") life.

He celebrated life by taking a walk on the beach.
They celebrate life by giving garden parties.
She celebrates life by smiling everyday.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are pretty good. To "celebrate life" is to enjoy one's life to the fullest as opposed to simply going through the movements. Exactly how this celebration manifests itself is different for everyone and each situation.

There is also a similar term, a "celebration of life" event or service. This is a gathering that takes the place of a funeral. In a celebration of life service, friends and family gather not to mourn the loss of the person, but to celebrate the positive effects the deceased had on their lives.

Comment: I like the answers above, but I like this idea, too: look up the dozens of synonyms for "celebrate" and see if you understand the meaning of each word, looking up origins and usage as necessary through the glory of internet searching. Then, and perhaps only then, will you have a full understanding of the meaning of "to celebrate life." I plan to do this as an exercise--I delight in the idea, which I think means I am celebrating life in the process. Etymology lovers, take note.